# wireless networking: can wicd switch wireless cards automatically

Tags: wireless-networking, slackware, switching, wicd

I have slackware64 13.37 installed on my laptop, with wicd 1.7.0 as network manager.
By default wicd connects using the internal wifi card.
I have a much better usb wifi card that I would prefer wicd to use.
How can I set wicd to first try to connect using the usb wifi card, but if it is not available, to switch to the internal wifi card?

The internal card is

> 04:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)

The usb card is

> Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8187 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8187 Wireless Adapter

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `Wicd` only allows a single wired and a single wireless interface at a time. Slackware-current now comes with `NetworkManager`, however, so if you want to run the latest development version you can use it instead of `wicd` (warning: I don't use `NetworkManager` so I can't say that it will do what you want, but it it more feature rich than `wicd`, so it may well).